# My installed transformers version is not considered by cabal-install

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, stackage

I am totally new to Haskell an cabal and I'm trying to make yesod work.

My cabal version is cabal-install version 1.20.0.3
using version 1.20.0.2 of the Cabal library

This is what happends when I tru to install alex:

```
$ cabal install alex
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: alex-3.1.4 (user goal)
next goal: QuickCheck (dependency of alex-3.1.4)
rejecting: QuickCheck-2.8.1, 2.8 (global constraint requires ==2.7.6)
trying: QuickCheck-2.7.6
next goal: transformers (dependency of QuickCheck-2.7.6)
rejecting: transformers-0.4.3.0, 0.4.2.0, 0.4.1.0, 0.3.0.0, 0.2.2.1, 0.2.2.0,
0.2.1.0, 0.2.0.0, 0.1.4.0, 0.1.3.0, 0.1.1.0, 0.1.0.1, 0.1.0.0, 0.0.1.0,
0.0.0.0, 0.4.0.0 (global constraint requires installed instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

Second attempt:

```
$ cabal install alex happy yesod-bin --allow-newer
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: alex-3.1.4 (user goal)
trying: QuickCheck-2.7.6/installed-1a8... (dependency of alex-3.1.4)
trying: tf-random-0.5/installed-ef3... (dependency of
QuickCheck-2.7.6/installed-1a8...)
next goal: primitive (dependency of tf-random-0.5/installed-ef3...)
rejecting: primitive-0.5.0.1/installed-8e5... (global constraint requires
==0.6)
rejecting: primitive-0.6 (conflict: tf-random =>
primitive==0.5.0.1/installed-8e5...)
rejecting: primitive-0.5.4.0, 0.5.3.0, 0.5.2.1, 0.5.1.0, 0.5.0.1, 0.5, 0.4.1,
0.4.0.1, 0.4, 0.3.1, 0.3, 0.2.1, 0.2, 0.1 (global constraint requires ==0.6)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

What do I have to do to install alex?

A related question is this one:
[cabal install --- global constraint requires installed instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745558/cabal-install-global-constraint-requires-installed-instance)

The comment by @kosmikus on that question is:

> So the Stackage LTS config file contains the constraint transformers
>   installed, meaning that only an already present version of
>   transformers can be used. This is reasonable, because GHC ships with a
>   specific version of transformers. For ghc-7.8, this is
>   transformers-0.3.0.0. For some reason, this installed version is not
>   considered by cabal-install. Your partial log doesn't contain
>   sufficient info to see why.

How can I fix my Stackage LTS config file? Where is it on Ubuntu?

Comment: You may find [this blog post about stackage 2.0](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/04/announcing-lts-2) and it's links helpful if you're unfamiliar with stackage. I agree with [Sibi's advice below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557459/my-installed-transformers-version-is-not-considered-by-cabal-install#comment49187290_30557659)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem was that my GHC was too old. I downloaded a newer version and solved the problem.

**Failed (and wrong) attempt**

You should have a `cabal.config` file in your current directory. Open it with any text editor and serach for the `transformers installed` string.

Once you have found it, replace it with `transformers ==0.4.3.0` or any other version you like.

It is a bad solution, because, as dfeurer writes:

> `transformers` sits very far down in the package dependency structure. I
>   believe it depends only on `base`; I imagine a large majority of
>   packages on Hackage depend, directly or indirectly, on it. If you
>   upgrade `transformers`, practically every dependency in the system will
>   go screwy, which is the opposite of what you're going for if you're
>   using Stackage.

---

**Clean solution by Sibi**

Use the stackage packages as it is. If you have some global package causing problem, then remove them and use stackage exclusively. Also using sandbox for each project is a good idea.

Comment: Note that this is not the recommended approach. Stackage is a curated set of packages that are know to build properly. Replacing their transformers with some random version may lead to breakage.

Comment: @Sibi what is the recommended approach?

Comment: To use the stackage packages as it is. If you have some global package causing problem, then I would remove them and use stackage exclusively. Also using sandbox for each project is a good idea.

Comment: @Sibi could you please provide me a link to some web page (or article, or book) where this is explained?

Comment: `transformers` sits *very* far down in the package dependency structure. I believe it depends only on `base`; I imagine a large majority of packages on Hackage depend, directly or indirectly, on it. If you upgrade `transformers`, practically every dependency in the system will go screwy, which is the opposite of what you're going for if you're using Stackage.

Comment: @dfeuer thank you. Is there a way to make `cabal` see the installed `transformers` version in situations like mine? Do I have to provide more information to debug that? If yes, which information?

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij, I'm no cabal expert.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `cabal install alex --allow-newer`

Comment: That does not solve the problem, see my secondo attempt in my question